# spring AnnotationUtils in 5.2 no longer searching parent classes?

Tags: java, spring

I've found a difference between 5.1.x and 5.2.x in springframework and I'm trying to figure out if it's something that I've done or a regression.

I have a bean scanner that will search for things in the context that are deprecated and with spring 5.2.x it no longer seems to scan the parent classes for annotations. I'm either doing something wrong, there's a bug, or the javadocs need to be updated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
           http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Zminimal</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <!-- <version>5.1.10.RELEASE</version> -->
      <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

```
package com.example;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils;

public class AnnotationTest {

    @Test
    public void isClassDeprecated_DirectlyOnclass() {
        assertTrue("should mark as deprecated", isClassDeprecated(TestDepricatedClass.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void isClassDeprecated_OnAbstractclass() {
        assertTrue("should mark as deprecated", isClassDeprecated(TestDepricatedAbstractClass.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void isClassDeprecated_OnSuperclass() {
        assertTrue("should mark as deprecated", isClassDeprecated(SubClass.class));
    }

    /* package */boolean isClassDeprecated(Class<?> clazz) {
        return null != AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(clazz, Deprecated.class);
    }

    /** Class used for testing. */
    @Deprecated
    public static class TestDepricatedClass {
    }

    /** Class used for testing. */
    @Deprecated
    public abstract static class TestDepricatedAbstractClass {
    }

    /** Class used for testing. */
    public static class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    }

    /** Class used for testing. */
    @Deprecated
    public static class SuperClass {
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's a regression and currently it's scheduled to be fixed in 5.2.2
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23929